# Can django @login_required be used on APIs used by a mobile app?

Tags: django, authentication, mobile, csrf

We're using django-notifications-hq to provide users with persistent notifications in our app. Until recently, they lived only in the web app, however now we want to show the notifications in the mobile app as well.
Also, our server is set up with CSRF.

All the endpoints provided by django-notifications-hq use `@login_required` annotation to verify that user is authenticated.

However, when we're trying to call any of those endpoints from our mobile app, we get 403 response. To be specific, the first OPTIONS request returnd 200, but then the following request for those APIs always results in 403.

This is *not* a problem when we're using i.e. django-rest-framework's `permissions.IsAuthenticated`.

The 403 returns this in the response:

```
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>
```

Suggesting it's a CSRF problem, even though mobile app obviously doesn't provide cookies in their requests (it's token-based authorization).

Is this a general issue with `@login_required` (perhaps it can't be used at all with token-based authorization) or is this some misconfiguration on our part? I couldn't find a clear answer when looking for solutions.

Is there a significant implementation difference between django's `@login_required` vs django-rest-framework 
`@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))`?

Comment: It doesn't *suggest* it's a CSRF problem. It is absolutely explicitly a CSRF problem. And, additionally, has nothing to do with the `login_required` decorator, but with the login view itself. So I don't know what your question is asking.

Comment: What I was trying to do, is get a confirmation that @login_required with CSRF doesn't work with token-basen authentication (as opposed to session-based authentication) that doesn't provide CSRF cookies, and how is it different than django-rest-framework handling of authentication.

Indeed, after digging some more I found the answer - django_rest_framework permission.IsAuthenticated has two separate flows and if you use token-based authentication, *it skips CSRF checks*, allowing mobile devices to authenticate even though they don't pass CSRF cookie.